# Should BizTalk Enterprise Single Sign-On be running on non-cluster servers?

Tags: biztalk

Should BizTalk Enterprise Single Sign-On be running on non-cluster servers?

We have 4 BizTalk servers, two of which are in a cluster, and are running EntSSO, FTP and POP hosts

I've noticed that the other two BTS servers are still running EntSSO

Is this right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**.  But, it must be running on clustered servers as well.

Meaning, Enterprise Single Sing-On must be running on every BizTalk Host Computer regardless of whether or not there are clustered Hosts.

The two situations are actually completely unrelated.

Huge Note:  This is also completely different from clustering the Master Secret Server.  The MSS should never be clustered on BizTalk Host Computers.

Answer (score 1):

BizTalk depends on Enterprise Single Sign On. The hosts cannot be started without it. 
The mechanics hasn't changed since BizTalk 2004. For further information see:
[Installing Enterprise Single Sign-On in a BizTalk Server Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251756(v=bts.10).aspx)

Comment: Read the MSDN bits, but they only discuss having both BTS servers in the cluster, with one active/passive ... not 2 in cluster and 2 "standalone"

Comment: I don't think you can install BizTalk without Enterprise Single Sign On. The BizTalk host services has a dependency on EntSSO service. Those will not start without EntSSO running.

Comment: But the EntSSO on the passive cluster is stopped, yet the host instances start fine, and presume the two non-cluster servers are also getting their SSO from the cluster, so why have EntSSO running on them?

Comment: IIRC; BizTalk itself stores port configuration in the encrypted SSO database. Partly a security measure. But it does force SSO to be dependency of BizTalk messaging engine. Hence the installation on any BizTalk runtime.